# Issue with UIViews. Do not want the back option in the top to show up

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am developing this iOS 8 app but I am having trouble to display what I want. When built, my app runs smoothly, but the thing is that I do not want the < Back tab to show up whenever the user is logged in.

My code works so if you provide the right credentials, the loginView logs you in and triggers the segue to the main app screen, which I have not developed yet, but it is there (The one that has the "User Logged in!" and "Display app content here" labels). As I said, it works perfectly fine but I am not sure what to do to get rid of that

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Home Screen]

Here is another screenshot to show the structure of my Storyboard:

[image]

Which kind of view do I need to use so I dont get that

Thank you for your time and advice!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewcontroller has a property called `navigationItem` that describes what is shown in the navigation bar. `navigationItem` has a property called `hidesBackButton` that you can set to true if you want to hide it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```